# How do I assign the same value for each key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am python beginner. I first use `dictionary`.

I have a dictionary it’s containing alphabet of key and arbitrary value of value as pair, I want to assign same value for each key simultaneously.I was trying to practice to operate dictionary as the following:

```
dict_ = {'a':1 , 'b': 2 , 'c': 3}

dict_ ['a'] = "It\'s an alphabet."
dict_ ['b'] = "It\'s an alphabet."
dict_ ['c'] = "It\'s an alphabet."

print dict_
```

Suppose I will have many keys, it’s too troublesome to set each value of the key  one by one.
Is there good idea to do?

Comment: Do you want to revise the dictionary you already have (your code does), or add a whole lot of additional values?

Comment: when I have a existing dictionary, I want to reset the values.

Comment: Got it. So the first part of my answer isn't what you're after (but see the second part).

Comment: By the way, inside double quotes you don't need to escape the single quote (and vice versa).

Comment: FWIW, the sentence "It's an alphabet." doesn't mean what you appear to think it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might need exactly what `defaultdict` was made for:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(lambda: "It's an elephant")
print(mydict["a"])
```

If you do it this way you won't have to explicitly set all the default values at all: They will spring into existence if you try to look up a key that does not exist.

If your goal is to zap existing values and replace them with a default, do it with some kind of loop or comprehension over the keys. I endorse @bfontaine's answer, but you can also do it this way as well (also works on older versions of python):

```
mydict = dict((key, "It's an elephant") for key in mydict)
```

Comment: OP already has a dictionary and want to modify it. `defaultdict` creates a `dict`-like object that’ll return `"It's an elephant"` even for the keys that weren’t in the original dictionary.

Comment: Indeed; it's clear now. On first reading I suspected that what's really going on would be better handled with a defaultdict than with mass value assignment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
dict_ = {'a':1 , 'b': 2 , 'c': 3}

dict_ = {k:"It\'s an alphabet." for k in dict_}
```

However this creates a new dictionary. Looping over the existing one is the best solution to do this in-place:

```
for k in dict_:
    dict_[k] = "It\'s an alphabet."
```

You can loop over all keys of a dictionary with `for k in mydict`:

```
for k in mydict:
    # this block of code will be executed once for each
    # key in the dictionary. You can get the current key
    # with `k`:
    print k
```

The code above will print each value of the dictionary.

Since you can assign to a key with `mydict[mykey] = myvalue`, all you have to do here is *for each key* assign `"It\'s an alphabet"` to it in the dictionary. This is what the code does:

```
# for each key `k` in the dictionary `dict_`
for k in dict_:
    # assign "It\'s an alphabet" to it:
    dict_[k] = "It\'s an alphabet"
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is similar to some of the earlier solutions. However, it uses the `dict.update` method to update the existing dictionary, with new (key, value) tuples created via a generator expression, so we don't create a temporary intermediate dictionary.

```
dict_ = {'a':1 , 'b': 2 , 'c': 3}
dict_.update((key, "It's an elephant") for key in dict_)
print dict_
```

**output**

```
{'a': "It's an elephant", 'c': "It's an elephant", 'b': "It's an elephant"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dict comprehension.

```
>>> dict_ = {'a':1 , 'b': 2 , 'c': 3}
>>> dict_ = {i:"It's an alphabet." for i in dict_}
>>> dict_
{'a': "It's an alphabet.", 'c': "It's an alphabet.", 'b': "It's an alphabet."}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.fromkeys`. It’s better than a `for` loop over the input dictionary.

```
dict_ = {'a':1 , 'b': 2 , 'c': 3}

print dict.fromkeys(dict_, "It\'s an alphabet.")
```

Description as the link:

[tutorialspoint - python - dictionary_fromkeys](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_fromkeys.htm)

Syntax
Following is the syntax for fromkeys() method −
dict.fromkeys(seq[, value]))
Parameters
  -seq -- This is the list of values which would be used for dictionary keys preparation.
  -value -- This is optional, if provided then value would be set to this value
I hope it can help you.

Comment: The OP wants to modify the existing dictionary, not create a new one.

Comment: What? What do you mean creating a new one? It's can give same value to each key for existing dicionary.

Comment: @BurgerKing OP wants to modify the existing dictionary; not create a new object; which is what `dict.fromkeys` does.

Comment: @bfontaine What does OP stand for?

Comment: This answer will be perfectly ok if you assign the new dict back to `dict_` instead of printing it. Yeah, there's a difference if there are other references to the same dict, but it's standard to filter collections this way.

Comment: @BurgerKing “Original Poster”. Here it’s the person who asked the question.

Comment: @alexis I disagree. You create a new dictionary in memory then assign it to `dict_` instead of modifying the object in-place. This is really bad for the memory complexity. It’s perfectly ok for short code snippets like this but not in the general case.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion: It's common python practice to "filter" collections by creating a replacement rather than edit in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set of keys already in hand then using `map` and `lambda` this can be achieved.

```
dict_ = {'a':1 , 'b': 2 , 'c': 3} 
# Set default message to each key
info=map(lambda key: (key, "It\'s an alphabet."), dict_.keys())
dict(info)
```

Output would be

```
{'a': "It's an alphabet.", 'b': "It's an alphabet.", 'c': "It's an alphabet."}
```